# Simple text substitution in OS X using keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I am constantly typing `résumé` in (Outlook) email messages.  Is there an easy way to associate this text with a keyboard shortcut?  I'd like this shortcut to be available in other applications (e.g. Word, Mail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use Autocorrect shortcuts:

- Go to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Text**
- Replace: `[[[` with: `résumé`
- (Make sure "correct spelling automatically" is checked)

The character combination `[[[` is just an example. Everytime I type `[[[` it's automatically replaced with `résumé`. This applies system wide. You can use any set of not often used character(s). It functions as a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I found that just after I posted the question.  Hard part is deciding what character sequence should represent `résumé`.

Comment: @craig any character sequence you wouldn't use normally while typing. I used `[[[` because I don't use that sequence often, except maybe in Terminal, which is exempt from autocorrection.

Comment: Interesting: works in Outlook and Mail (subject and body fields), but not in Word, Excel, Safari, or Firefox.

Comment: Some apps, like Word, have their own substitution tables and do not use stuff from Apple.  In Apple apps, you must also look at Edit > Substitutions to make sure it is activated for the particular app.